# How to use Bootstrap in DOM Pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf, html2pdf

I have an html invoice template designed which i have designed using HTML & Bootstrap. But when the same i try to convert to PDF using DOM PDF bootstrap is not working.  I have included all links online Can any one tell me how to use bootstrap with DOM Pdf.

Links Used :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unithosgroup.com/demo/css/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unithosgroup.com/demo/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: DOM PDF is an old lib. It does not work well with CSS3 and HTML5. If you only want to render your html page to pdf use something like wkhtml2pdf or headless chrome

Comment: There might be some way to use css i guess

Comment: Your question needs more detail. You state that it "doesn't work" but that doesn't really tell us what's broken. Does it not render anything at all? Or does it render and not look correct? What version of Dompdf are you using? Do you have a sample of the HTML so that others can debug the issue? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Still, I will note that Dompdf currently has a deficient that will affect rendering. Dompdf does not yet support the `box-sixing` CSS property, which is important to how Bootstrap lays out content. Still, it should be able to display some form of your document even without that support.